# Avoid update POM versions for next development iteration with maven-release-plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm doing my first release with *maven-release-plugin* and git. Instead of tagging I'm using the *release:branch* goal. I'm agree with the complete relase-flow process except in one point: all local dependencies are automatically updated to the next SNAPSHOT version in the development branch.

This is my concrete situation: I'm working in a project with more than 20 maven projects. Let's say all of them are in SNAPSHOT version during development. I want to make a release with the maven plugin. After the release is done, all POM versions have been incremented and set again to SNAPSHOT. If I need to make a change in just one line of code of one project (fix a bug) and I make a new release, all projects (by default) must increment their version again when I've just changed **one of them**.

In my opinion, it makes more sense to continue the development with the state of the last release (all version **without** SNAPSHOT). In the next development iteration, I can set manually the next SNAPSHOT version only in these projects that I have changed. In the next release, only the changed projects will be "promoted" to a new version but not all of them.

I think this situation is not exceptional but I didn't found information how to do it (and I don't know if I'm breaking the "release" phylosophy...)

Somedy knows how to avoid update all POMs to the next SNAPSHOT version and leave the POM files as the relase version?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

The idea of a multimodule project is that all modules are part of the same release cycle. Even is some modules contain no changes, they will be part of the release. As some may say: versions are cheap.
The benefits are bigger compared to the ideal picture you described: it is much easier to manage the versions and to control inter-module dependencies.
Keep in mind that both trunk and branches should *always* have a SNAPSHOT version, since these are the working copies. If you use final versions, releases will fail, since you can't tag the same version twice, neither can you deploy(=upload) the same version twice. This is very important, because Maven relies on the definition that final versions are immutable, i.e. Maven will never download a final version again once it is available in the local repository.

So if some modules don't have the same release-cycle as the total multimodule project, you should move them out of this multimodule project (or release them all at once).

Comment: Ok, now I understand the "modular" philosophy:). With this information, my next question would be: do you know if there is a way in Maven to configure the release plugin to make a release for **only** these SNAPSHOTS that have changed since last release? In this case, my scenario would work, it isn't?

Comment: Mavens scope is current build and previous build (for support of incremental build), so Maven can't detect what has been changed compared to previous release. Also be aware that the maven-release-plugin doesn't support tag-per-module, because the maven-release-plugin must be able to do a checkout by tag and rebuild the whole (multimodule-)project again. So the most reliable way is to create 1 tag containing the complete multimodule. You could try to select releasable modules by using -pl, I haven't tried it and it'll make the process more complex. Just ask yourself: does it really matter?

Comment: I'm agree with you, it would be simpler to update all POMs...but sincerely, I don't like the idea to have different versions of a module that didn't change its sources! Don't you find this situation as "dirty"? :)

Comment: Let's say it is not perfect, but the chance of mistakes will reduce a lot. As said, it's all about release cycles. If a module has its own release-cycle, move it out the multimodule project. But now you are responsible to keep all dependency references up to date. I could challenge you to design your solution :) That is: detect changes based on revision; exclude unchanged modules when tagging. And in the end this should work for all SCM's, but I'm pretty sure already fixing it for a single SCM is hard. As you can see:the main problem is how to instruct the SCM correctly,Maven can easily follow

Answer (score 2):

The differences between releasing individual modules, applications or application systems are summarized in my slideshare presentation http://www.slideshare.net/geertpante/version-mgmt-in-maven (slide 20 and following).

What we sometimes do is set the snapshot version to e.g. 2.0-SNAPSHOT, and do releases as 1.x.y. So in development, we always keep using 2.0-SNAPSHOT, but when we release, we choose older versions, e.g. 1.3, 1.4, and choose 2.0-SNAPSHOT as the next release version.

Also, if you use git, take a look at https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jgit-flow/wiki/Home. One of the advantages is it keeps a single development branch, and only the releases are merged to the master branch:

```
mvn jgitflow:release-start -DreleaseVersion=1.2 -DdevelopmentVersion=2.0-SNAPSHOT
mvn jgitflow:release-finish -DreleaseVersion=1.2 -DdevelopmentVersion=2.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: I like the solution because solves all the problems related to dependencies among POMs (and this is a very good point). Nevertheless, when you want to make a new release, you need to 1) merge you devolpment version (2.0.0-SNAPSHOT) with your last release version (e.g 1.1). 2) Increment the release version (1.2) and deploy it. Do you do this process manually or it's possible to make it automatically with maven?

Comment: This is done automatically with maven using the jgitflow plugin mentioned above. It merges the releases automatically to the development branch immediately after each release.